# strange behaviour - irb and rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

The *irb* is giving **true** at first and then **false** always for the command **require rails**.

The *rails console* is giving **false** always.

How's this happening?

Please see below cmd-

```
~/Workspaces/eclipse/image_cropper_ws/image_cropper$ irb

1.9.2-p180 :001 > require 'rails'
=> true 
1.9.2-p180 :002 > require 'rails'
=> false 
1.9.2-p180 :003 > exit



~/Workspaces/eclipse/image_cropper_ws/image_cropper$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.8)

1.9.2-p180 :001 > require 'rails'
=> false 
1.9.2-p180 :002 > require 'rails'
=> false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

require returns `false` when what you're trying to require is already loaded - the first time you `require 'rails'`, it's not loaded, and require returns true.
The second time you `require 'rails'`, it is already loaded and require returns false.

Rails is always loaded in the rails console.

Comment: Oh I thought that require command will give true only if it is successfully requiring rails for our project else false. The point is it is returning according to loading at the moment of writing it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs for [require](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require), it states

> Loads the given name, returning true if successful and false if the feature is already loaded.

So the first time you call `require` in irb it loads and returns true. The second time it is already loaded so it returns false.

When you call `rails c` it loads irb with your rails environment so it must have already required `rails`